# CSS opacity not working in this case

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to apply opacity to my article DIV using opacity:O.9 (it works well everytime I use it on other projects). Now for some reason it does not work and can't figure out why. Could it be linked to the backstrech plugin? You can [see the page here](http://goo.gl/rMIYJ) Thanks

```
#article {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    left: 200px;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    opacity:0.9;
    padding: 30px 50px 50px 50px;
    z-index: 1000;

}
```

Comment: It is because of `fadeInLeftBig` css animation that you using in `.fadeInLeftBig` class

Comment: Don't link to your page : build a minimal example reproducing your problem.

Comment: I have no much time but a quick view your #article opacity is changed for some reason. If you inspect it, on style section you will see `opacity: 0.9` but on computed style section you can see `opacity: 1`. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks Cherniv, indeed this is due to that - all set now!

Comment: i've posted it like answer , you can "accept" it! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of `fadeInLeftBig` css animation that you using in `.fadeInLeftBig` class